# A new case for an old build

Tags: case, enclosure

When I built my PC a year ago, I bought a really cheap case. It did not have USB 3.0 or audio on the front panel, and I regret it now. I already have new case fans for the thing, and it runs quietly, but I really do want a new case.

The case I want:

- Black and/or red, to match the rest of the build
- Has a case window on the side
- Has support for 2 or more 5 and 1/2 inch drives
- Has front facing USB 3.0 and Audio
- Costs less than $60
- Supports full ATX motherboard and Power Supply
- Is large enough 12.5 inch graphics card
- Has cable management at least somewhat in mind
- Is wide enough to support the Hyper 212 Evo CPU cooler
- If a cover goes over the front of the case, the hinge must be on the right side
- I do not need decent fans, as I have 4 red and very quiet corsair fans
- **Optional** If possible, I would love support for USB type C, although my motherboard only has 3.0 headers, so an adapter would be needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [Enermax Ostrog](http://www.frys.com/product/7363704?source=google&gclid=CjwKEAiAluG1BRDrvsqCtYWk81gSJACZ2BCeaRAUnwCiRX7om1JQGVzz4pRwBM6XmqjedXMTl4AXpBoCzi3w_wcB). Although it does not meet the USB Type-C requirement (Which I honestly doubt that any case under $60 would have at this point), it does fufil your other requirements. I have personally used this case in the past, and I can say that it does indeed work well. On a side note, the side panel is essentially one huge window; which means weekly cleaning (At least I did). Great case that can be had at Frys for $44

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to find case which meets all your requirements in this budget but I have two recommendations under $70:

- [Corsair Carbide Series SPEC-03](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811139040) - $70 on newegg.com. It is black with red lighted fan in front panel and meets all your requirements without USB type C support. This case has quite good cable managment and good airflow.
- [Thermaltake Commander G41](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811133253) - $65 + shipping on newegg.com. It also meets all your requirements without USB type C support. It has nice HDD and 5.25 mounting system and good amount of space for cable managment.